# Bug in facebook single sign on in ios6

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, ios6

Bug in facebook single sign on in ios6[image]

Please check the above image. Whn i click on cancel it's not going back to the app instead it's stays in facebook itself.  This is happening only in iOS6. In iOS5.1.1 it's working perfectly. Please help!!!

Thanks...

Comment: no i tested in device only, i tried in simulator, it is showing only Okay button  but when i tried in device both buttons(Cancel and Okay) are showing...

Comment: One more questions - is this screenshot from their mobile app, Safari, or in-app popup?

Comment: While integrating Facebook to my app i'm getting this popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should submit your bug to Facebook and provide as much detail as possible (including some sample code) https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/create

Answer (score 0):

User after pressing cancel in FB app when comes back to your app manually, your handler will be called with status as FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed. So check for this status and raise proper error message or try opening the session again.